# Is it possible to use multiple trailing closures in swift?

Tags: swift

I know it is possible to define methods which accept closures like this:

A. Single closure as input parameter

```
func testOfClosures (flag: Int, closure1: () -> ())
{
     closure1()
}
```

B. Multiple closures as input parameters

```
func testOfClosures (flag: Int, closure1: () -> (), closure2: () -> (), closure3: () ->  ())
{
    switch flag
    {
        case 1:
             closure1()
        case 2:
             closure2()
        default:
             closure3()
    }
}
```

Interestingly in first case we can invoke it like this:

```
testOfClosures(1){
    println("print closure 1")
}
```

but in second case, we cannot invoke it like this:

```
testOfClosures(1,{
    println("print closure 1")
},
{
    println("print closure 2")
})
{
    println("print closure 3")
}
```

and we have to invoke it like this:

```
testOfClosures(1,{
    println("print closure 1")
},
{
    println("print closure 2")
},
{
    println("print closure 3")
})
```

Any reasons?

Comment: Beyond, "because they said so", it's pretty much opinion.  The short-cut notation of a trailing closure is documented as only applying to a single last argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can do it since **Swift 5.3**.

Please see this example

```
// Multiple trailing closure arguments
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
  self.view.alpha = 0
} completion: { _ in
  self.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Credit and more infos from this [Proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0279-multiple-trailing-closures.md)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the trailing closure syntax is very specific about the position of the opening `{` and requires it to be on the same line as the closing `)`

The below works

```
testOfClosures(1,{
    println("print closure 1")
},
{
    println("print closure 2")
}) {
    println("print closure 3")
}
```

As far as multiple trailing closures, that is not possible.  The documentation specifically states only the final closure as using the special syntax.